# How to fill null values if nothing is returned from the database in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am developing a POS Application where when no Coupon is applied I am saving Coupon ID as Zero but when I am printing the report and gelling the last sale with the below procedure the Coupon Code is obviously NULL and hence it cannot find any data to return. Please suggest how to save/don't save the coupon if applied or not applied.

**Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PrintAfterSale]
    @SaleId NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT
        Sale.InvoiceNumber,
        Sale.ShippingRate,
        Sale.DiscountApplied,
        ISNULL(Coupons.CouponCode,'None'),
        Customer.CustomerName, 
        Customer.CustomerAddressLine1, 
        Customer.CustomerAddressLine2, 
        Customer.CustomerAddressPin, 
        Customer.CustomerEmail, 
        Customer.CustomerPhone,
        Sale.SaleDate,
        Sale.GrandTotal
    FROM
        [Sale]
        INNER JOIN
        [Customer] ON
        Sale.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
        INNER JOIN
        Coupons ON
        Sale.CouponId = Coupons.Id
    WHERE 
        Sale.SaleId = @SaleId
END
```

Comment: Are you sure this is C#?

Comment: Yeah! I using the code behind in C# This is the procedure I am using to get data

Comment: Why do you use `INNER JOIN` with `Coupons` table? If you use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you get the data you want.

Comment: That really worked. Thanks a lot :)